# R: export multiple workbook excel from a dataset by a variable

Tags: r, excel, sas

i have a statistical df organised by years, for example 5 and i'll would like to export my table in 5 different Excel Workbook, how can i do? First i used SAS and i did it with macros like this

```
        %let elenco = gen feb mar apr giu;

        %macro export;

        %local i;
        %let i = 0;
        %do %until (%scan(&elenco,&i+1) = );

        %let i = %eval(&i+1);
        %let ele=%scan(&elenco,&i);

        data month_&i;
        set tot;
        where month="&ele";
        run;

        proc export data = month_&i
        outfile = "C:\prova_&i.xls"
        dbms = excelcs replace;
        sheet="month_&i";
        run;

        %end;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll need to translate this script in R

Answer (score 0):

Ods excel does not work well with big datasets. But it could be worth a try.

```
* Sort by your sheet-variable ;
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=work.class;
    by age;
run;


ods excel
    file='c:\temp\mult_sheet.xlsx'
    options(sheet_interval='output' sheet_name='#byval1');

proc print data=work.class label noobs;
    by age;
run;

ods excel close;
```